# pivot_longer function omits column

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

When `select()` uses argument `contains("T")`, the **time** column is lost. The function works when other character elements `"PAR"` or `"RH"` are used.

here a subset of my data

```
#ad_1_top_n <- ad_1[1:3, ]
#dput(ad_1_top_n)

ad_1 <- structure(list(time = 0:2, X1c.PAR1 = c(125.73, 125.76, 125.73
), X1c.PAR2 = c(27.25, 27.25, 27.25), X1c.PAR3 = c(10.03, 10.14, 
9.99), X1c.PAR4 = c(0.07, 0.07, 0.07), X1c.T1 = c(21.28, 21.28, 
21.27), X1c.T2 = c(20.19, 20.18, 20.18), X1c.T3 = c(19.95, 19.95, 
19.95), X1c.T4 = c(20.42, 20.4, 20.4), X1c.RH1 = c(73.57, 73.67, 
73.83), X1c.RH2 = c(84.02, 84.04, 84.06), X1c.RH3 = c(82.35, 
82.35, 82.36), X1c.RH4 = c(76.94, 76.91, 76.94), X1b.PAR1 = c(108.89, 
108.93, 108.93), X1b.PAR2 = c(61.9, 61.9, 61.9), X1b.PAR3 = c(40.1, 
40.1, 40.1), X1b.PAR4 = c(0.06, 0.06, 0.1), X1b.T1 = c(20.45, 
20.45, 20.46), X1b.T2 = c(20.22, 20.26, 20.26), X1b.T3 = c(20.63, 
20.6, 20.61), X1b.T4 = c(20.9, 20.89, 20.89), X1b.RH1 = c(76.2, 
76.2, 76.26), X1b.RH2 = c(79.18, 79.21, 79.21), X1b.RH3 = c(75.33, 
75.36, 75.47), X1b.RH4 = c(73.52, 73.58, 73.64), X1p.PAR1 = c(144.9, 
144.97, 144.94), X1p.PAR2 = c(116.96, 117.03, 116.96), X1p.PAR3 = c(85.2, 
85.24, 85.2), X1p.PAR4 = c(2.73, 2.73, 2.73), X1p.T1 = c(20.49, 
20.5, 20.48), X1p.T2 = c(20.62, 20.62, 20.61), X1p.T3 = c(19.99, 
20, 19.98), X1p.T4 = c(20.31, 20.3, 20.27), X1p.RH1 = c(77.79, 
77.87, 77.97), X1p.RH2 = c(77.01, 77.04, 77.05), X1p.RH3 = c(81.93, 
82.03, 82.08), X1p.RH4 = c(77.98, 77.75, 77.72), X2c.PAR1 = c(NaN, 
NaN, NaN), X2c.PAR2 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), X2c.PAR3 = c(NaN, NaN, 
NaN), X2c.PAR4 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), X2c.T1 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), 
    X2c.T2 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), X2c.T3 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), X2c.T4 = c(NaN, 
    NaN, NaN), X2c.RH1 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), X2c.RH2 = c(NaN, NaN, 
    NaN), X2c.RH3 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), X2c.RH4 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN
    ), X2b.PAR1 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), X2b.PAR2 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN
    ), X2b.PAR3 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), X2b.PAR4 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN
    ), X2b.T1 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), X2b.T2 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), 
    X2b.T3 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), X2b.T4 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), X2b.RH1 = c(NaN, 
    NaN, NaN), X2b.RH2 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), X2b.RH3 = c(NaN, NaN, 
    NaN), X2b.RH4 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), X2p.PAR1 = c(NaN, NaN, 
    NaN), X2p.PAR2 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), X2p.PAR3 = c(NaN, NaN, 
    NaN), X2p.PAR4 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), X2p.T1 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN
    ), X2p.T2 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), X2p.T3 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), 
    X2p.T4 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), X2p.RH1 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), X2p.RH2 = c(NaN, 
    NaN, NaN), X2p.RH3 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), X2p.RH4 = c(NaN, NaN, 
    NaN)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

and here the functions, with the third one causing the problem:

```
library(tidyr)

adl_1_PAR_pivot <- ad_1 %>% select(time, contains("PAR")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("PAR"), names_to = "key", values_to = "PAR") %>% 
separate(col = "key", into = c("Dummy1", "Location", "Position", "Dummy2", "Height"), 
         sep = c(1,2,3,7), remove = TRUE)  %>%
select(-Dummy1, -Dummy2)

adl_1_RH_pivot <- ad_1 %>% select(time, contains("RH")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("RH"), names_to = "key", values_to = "RH") %>% 
  separate(col = "key", into = c("Dummy1", "Location", "Position", "Dummy2", "Height"), 
           sep = c(1,2,3,6), remove = TRUE)  %>%
  select(-Dummy1, -Dummy2)

adl_1_T_pivot <- ad_1 %>% select(time, contains("T")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("T"), names_to = "key", values_to = "T") %>% 
  separate(col = "key", into = c("Dummy1", "Location", "Position", "Dummy2", "Height"), 
           sep = c(1,2,3,5), remove = TRUE)  %>%
  select(-Dummy1, -Dummy2)
```

for some reason the problem does not occur when `gather` is used instead of `pivot_longer`:

```
adl_1_T <- ad_1 %>% select(time, contains("T")) %>% 
  gather(key = key, value = T, -time) %>%
  separate(col = "key", into = c("Dummy1","Location", "Position", "Dummy2","Height"), 
           sep = c(1,2,3,5), remove = TRUE) %>%
  select(-Dummy1, -Dummy2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that `contains()` ignores the case of your value by default so it's also matching the "time" column. You can see that if you run `select(ad_1, contains("T"))` you will also get the "time" column in the output.

To turn off that feature, use `contains("T", ignore.case=FALSE)`, for example

```
adl_1_T_pivot <- ad_1 %>% select(time, contains("T")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("T", ignore.case=FALSE), names_to = "key", values_to = "T") %>% 
  separate(col = "key", into = c("Dummy1", "Location", "Position", "Dummy2", "Height"), 
           sep = c(1,2,3,5), remove = TRUE)  %>%
  select(-Dummy1, -Dummy2)
```